# External disk recognized but reported as "unformatted" and will not mount

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive

I used an external (2.5") disk to do a Time Machine backup one day, and the next day when I connected it again, Disk Utility recognized the drive, but reported it as "unformatted" (OS X however did not give the usual "This disk is unformatted, do you wish to format it?" prompt like it usually does when an unformatted disk is connected).

I tried running Data Rescue to scan the disk, but it was unable to do anything (didn't report the disk as corrupt, just that it couldn't read it).

Is my disk foobared? I'd like to get the files back...

The disk appears to be spinning. I also have a second disk of the same model (bought at the same time), so I could try replacing the controller, I guess?

Advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried moving the HDD to a different (known to be working) enclosure?

Comment: @Daniel OS X detects the hard drive model and size properly so I don't think it's the enclosure. I did however, try another enclosure and cable as well to rule that out.

Comment: @Mokubai The HDD won't mount (at least through Disk Utility and Data Rescue) and is reported as unformatted, so unfortunately I don't think that link will work?

Comment: @Mokubai This can't be an NTFS drive, Time Machine only works with HFS journal file systems

Comment: @DK_ Have you tried verifying/repairing the disk in Disk Utility?  I've seen this fix missing partitions and some other weird problems.  Worth a shot

Comment: @Hefewe1zen Disk Utility can't mount the disk so it can't verify/repair it. It's labeling the disk as unformatted.

Comment: @DK_ That doesn't sound good, I would run the manufacturers diagnostics if possible.  FYI There is a utility called Disk Warrior that can possibly recover data.

Comment: @Hefewe1zen Disk Warrior won't recognize the disk at all (does not show up in the drop down of available drives), nor does smartmontools find it. Samsung only has Windows utilities, but I'll give them a try in a VM.